# Why am I getting a "resource busy" error?

Tags: esp32, arduino-ide

I am currently working on a file in the arduino IDE and I am running into a problem I had not been encountering until recently. [Image shows error I am receiving upon upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RP6tk.png). Sometimes I am able to unpload files with no problem and this error doesnt occur but sometimes it does occur and I am no longer able to upload anything. The file I uploaded that I initially started noticing this was an example file in the Ethernet_Generic library called UdpNTPClient. Im not sure if maybe this file just backs up my upload or if its lingering in the background.

The hardware I'm uploading to is an ESP32. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: it is a problem of the IDE 2 release candidate versions. use Arduino IDE 1.8+

Comment: @Juraj is there anyway to unupdate the IDE 2? I wasn't experiencing this problem before and it still works but not very often.

Comment: just delete it and download and install the stable version